# ¿Cómo añadir ciertos valores a una tabla generada con descr() en R markdown?

Tags: r, tablas, markdown, visualización-de-datos

Estoy elaborando una tabla de presentación con R markdown con determinados estadísticos descriptivos de un dataframe. Para ello, cargo `library(printr)` e introduzco mis variables de interés en `descr(data)`, que es un comando dentro de la librería `summarytools` que genera una tabla con ciertos valores descriptivos. Sin embargo, a la tabla que se me genera quiero **añadirle otros elementos**, como por ejemplo, el error estándar de cada variable al introducirla en un `glm(*)`.

Es decir, que con mis variables de interés estoy elaborando un modelo logit binomial y quisiera añadir a la tabla generada por descr(data) ciertos resultados que devuelve el objeto `glm`, como por ejemplo el **error estándar de cada variable**.

¿Hay alguna alternativa a tener que crear una nueva tabla desde cero? ¿Existe algún paquete que me facilite esta labor? Porque crear dicha tabla desde cero me llevaría mucho tiempo para lo poco que deseo añadir a la tabla generada por el comando `descr(data)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta es una opción generando el sumario descripctivo con `skimr` y organizando los estadísticos de interés del modelo con `broom`.

`skim()` crea sumarios que se pueden pasar fácilmente a data frame. Luego ajustas el modelo y con `tidy` pasas los coeficientes, error, etc. también a data frame. Luego un join por nombre de variable/coeficiente y finalmente elegir las columnas que saldrán en la tabla y renombrarlas a español en el mismo paso.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(skimr)
library(broom)

mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(gear), factor) %>% 
  select(mpg, wt, gear, cyl) -> limpio

skim(limpio) %>% 
  as_tibble() -> descriptivos


modelo <- glm(gear~mpg+wt+cyl, family = binomial(), data = limpio)
tidy(modelo) %>% 
  rename(skim_variable = term) %>% #para que coincida el nombre en el join
  inner_join(descriptivos)  %>% 
  select(variable = skim_variable, 
         coeficiente = estimate, 
         error = std.error, 
         media = numeric.mean,
         desviación = numeric.sd
         )

  Joining, by = "skim_variable"
  # A tibble: 3 x 5
  variable coeficiente error media desviación
  <chr>          <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
1 mpg        -0.000243 0.311 20.1       6.03 
2 wt         -2.49     1.80   3.22      0.978
3 cyl        -0.384    0.671  6.19      1.79
```

Funciona bien para variables independientes continuas, pero obviamente tiene problemas cuando es factor, ya que tendremos k-1 variables dummy y solamente una fila de descriptivos. Se le podría buscar una solución pasando a `skim()` la matriz de modelo hecha con `model.matrix` o similar. De hecho en ese caso tb podrías usar los mismos estadísticos de una continua, ya que la media sería la proporción de esa categoría. La desviación estándar no tendría mucho sentido, de todos modos.

Comment: Muchas gracias. ¿cómo podría añadir el valor máximo y el valor mínimo de cada variable a la tabla generada?

Comment: Vale, simplemente tengo que añadir `numeric.p0` para el valor mínimo y `numeric.p100` a la tabla.